# multiple facebook send to messenger buttons

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a list of json objects on the page, and each of them contains id of page. I want facebook send-to-messenger button be visible in every row of my data table on page. But when I iterate, only one button is visible. And it's not working. How to do that in loop?

I have a static part

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '<appid>',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and dynamic part

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
//...
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger"+
    'messenger_app_id="<appid>"'+
    'page_id="'+value.id+'"'+
    'data-ref="WELCOME_OPTIN_TOKEN"'+
    'color="blue"'+
    'size="standard">
//...
}
```

value.id is page id

How to do that? Or is there any javascript function that can accomplish it?

Answer (score 1):

You are generating them on the fly with JavaScript, so you have to parse the Plugins with [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) right after adding them to the DOM. Make sure you use `FB` after `FB.init` though.

For example:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '<appid>',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        //...
        <div class="fb-send-to-messenger"+
            'messenger_app_id="<appid>"'+
            'page_id="'+value.id+'"'+
            'data-ref="WELCOME_OPTIN_TOKEN"'+
            'color="blue"'+
            'size="standard">
        //...
        }
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```